# How to keep the design of jquery buttons even grouped?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

By using jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery-ui-1.10.2.js, I draw three independant buttons like so:

```
<button id="bt1">bt1</button>
<button id="bt2">bt2</button> 
<button id="bt3">bt3</button>
```

very nice buttons with rounded corners.
If I group them like so:

```
<div id="buttonList">
<button id="bt1">bt1</button>
<button id="bt2">bt2</button> 
<button id="bt3">bt3</button> 
</div>
```

and initialise like so:

```
$("#buttonList").buttonset();
```

Then each button hasn't anymore the rounded corners.
Therefore, how to evict this effect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.buttonset()` that is specificly designed to group buttons and suppress round corners. Just add a class name to your buttons like `<button id="btn1" class="myButtons" ...` and do `$(".myButtons).button();`